# Javascript For Loop index returning "[object Object] - undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to run one function to many elements,
so I'm using a for loop. I dont understand why i'm not getting any values.

```
    var i;
var aFields = ["#business1A","#business1B","#business1C","#business1D","#business2A","#business2B","#business2C","#business2D",
                "#business3A","#business3B","#business3C","#business3D","#business4A","#business4B","#business4C","#business4D",
                "#business5A","#business5B","#business5C","#business5D","#business6A","#business6B","#business6C","#business6D"];
for (i = 0; i < aFields.length; i++) {
    $(aFields[i]).keyup(function(){
        alert($(aFields[i]+'Warning') + " - " +$(aFields[i]).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i;
var aFields = ["#business1A","#business1B","#business1C","#business1D","#business2A","#business2B","#business2C","#business2D",
                "#business3A","#business3B","#business3C","#business3D","#business4A","#business4B","#business4C","#business4D",
                "#business5A","#business5B","#business5C","#business5D","#business6A","#business6B","#business6C","#business6D"];
for (i = 0; i < aFields.length; i++) {
  (function(j){
    $(aFields[j]).keyup(function(){
        alert(($(this).attr('id')+'Warning') + " - " +$(this).val());
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: wrapping it in a function is unnecessary if you are just going to use `this`.  I'd definitely prefer it over the closure method, since it is cleaner.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for the light speed replies! Stackoverflow Rocks! :p

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using the variable `i` in the callback function for the event handler. The event happens when the loop has finished, so the variable contains an index that is beyond the last item in the array.

To use the value of the variable from the iteration where you bind the event, you can create a variable for each iteration by creating a scope, using an immediately executed function expression:

```
var i;
var aFields = ["#business1A","#business1B","#business1C","#business1D","#business2A","#business2B","#business2C","#business2D",
                "#business3A","#business3B","#business3C","#business3D","#business4A","#business4B","#business4C","#business4D",
                "#business5A","#business5B","#business5C","#business5D","#business6A","#business6B","#business6C","#business6D"];
for (i = 0; i < aFields.length; i++) {
  (function(j){
    $(aFields[j]).keyup(function(){
        alert($(aFields[j]+'Warning') + " - " +$(aFields[j]).val());
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the [wrong usage of the closure variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) `i`, the variable is shared between all the keyup handlers so when the loop ends `i` will have the value `aFields.length` so `aFields[i]` will return undefined.

Try

```
var aFields = ["#business1A", "#business1B", "#business1C", "#business1D", "#business2A", "#business2B", "#business2C", "#business2D",
    "#business3A", "#business3B", "#business3C", "#business3D", "#business4A", "#business4B", "#business4C", "#business4D",
    "#business5A", "#business5B", "#business5C", "#business5D", "#business6A", "#business6B", "#business6C", "#business6D"];

$.each(aFields, function (i, val) {
    $(val).keyup(function () {
        alert($(val + 'Warning') + " - " + $(val).val());
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, However, I'm only getting the second value, the first still comes as "[object]".

Comment: @MichelFigueiredo `$(val + 'Warning')` will evaluate to a jQuery object - what do you want there?

Comment: i want to get hold of the actual id string so that I can pass into another function. that's working now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good explanations of how closures work, but the cleanest solution is to use `this` to refer to the selected object:

```
var i;
var aFields = ["#business1A","#business1B","#business1C","#business1D","#business2A","#business2B","#business2C","#business2D",
            "#business3A","#business3B","#business3C","#business3D","#business4A","#business4B","#business4C","#business4D",
            "#business5A","#business5B","#business5C","#business5D","#business6A","#business6B","#business6C","#business6D"];
for (i = 0; i < aFields.length; i++) {
    $(aFields[i]).keyup(function(){
        alert(this.id + ' Warning - ' + this.value);
    });
}
```